# Plot only edges of triangles with matplotlib triplot

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, delaunay

A [triplot](http://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.triplot.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.triplot) of Delaunay simplices returns a list of two line2D objects, edges and nodes:

```
tri=scipy.spatial.Delaunay(points)
plt.triplot(points[:,0],points[:,1],tri.simplices.copy(),'k-o', label='Delaunay\ntriangulation')
```

How can I to plot a Delaunay triangulation without markers for the triangle nodes, (only the edges)?
Alternatively, I want to remove the marker entry from the legend (replacing 'k-0' with 'k-' still produces two entries in the legend).
[image: delaunay]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `plt.triplot` produces two legend entries. The first of those are the edges, the second contains the points (nodes). Even if the marker is set to `marker=None`, this legend entry will be present.

The easiest way to get rid of the legend entry, is to obtain the legend handles (`ax.get_legend_handles_labels()`) and create a legend only using the first of those.

```
h, l = plt.gca().get_legend_handles_labels()
plt.legend(handles=[h[0]],labels=[l[0]])
```

At this point it's the user's choice whether to have the nodes marked (`"k-o"`) or not (`"k-"`); there will only be one legend entry.

[image]

```
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(6)
import scipy.spatial
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

points=np.random.rand(7, 2)

tri=scipy.spatial.Delaunay(points)
plt.triplot(points[:,0],points[:,1],tri.simplices.copy(),'k-o',
            label='Delaunay\ntriangulation')

h, l = plt.gca().get_legend_handles_labels()
plt.legend(handles=[h[0]],labels=[l[0]])
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks! That was indeed the easiest way. And now I know how to control legend entries.